# EC2 container stucks when I install OpenVPN server on it

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-web-services, openvpn

I'm facing an issue with fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation on AWS and OpenVPN server.

When I setup Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside my EC2 container — everything works fine and reboot as well. I can access my instance via SSH.

But when I install OpenVPN as a server, it works after install, client can connect to it, traffic goes well on both networks and when I reboot my instance with OpenVPN server, I won't be able to access it via SSH anymore.

That's the screenshot of my EC2 container after executing reboot command:

[image: ec2 screenshot]

I also disabled Source/Dest check on it. There is OpenVPN server config: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7bf4e95928ee8c997f5a39d6729e4def

At the same time, I have OpenVPN client on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it works well after reboot.

I'd really appreciate any help to solve this issue.

UPDATE 11 OCT: It works perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04. Then problem should be in systemd?

Comment: Disabling source/destination is typically done for a NAT instance, which this is similar to but not quite the same. I'd try enabling it again. I'm most likely wrong here, but it's easy so it's worth a shot.

Comment: @tim, No, it works as a NAT instance to route traffic from 172.32.0.0/21 to 172.32.8.0/21 that is located in the different AWS region